# Como leer archivos de windows con Nextjs & typeorm?

Tags: nextjs, typeorm

Estoy teniendo problemas para encontrar una solución a mi problema actual por eso escribo aca.

Tengo una API basada en Nodejs con Nextjs y TypeORM.

**Lo que estoy intentando hacer es que al entrar en una pantalla especifica en el front dispare una request y me lea, me levante, ciertos archivos dentro de el explorador de windows.**

El problema esta en que he buscado bastante y no he encontrado una solucion clara.
Vi que con Multer podes subir un archivo pero no es lo que busco. Tambien con FS se puede hacer pero segun encontre no funciona con Nextjs.

Alguien tiene experiencia con algo similar? Me vendria muy bien un ejemplo. Encaminarme un poco porque estoy perdido.

Gracias

Comment: Este link responde tu pregunta? https://vercel.com/guides/loading-static-file-nextjs-api-route